# Python define bitwise

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that accepts 'data' as a parameter. Being new to python I wasn't really sure that that was even a type.

I noticed when printing something of that type it would be

```
b'h'
```

if I encoded the letter h. Which dosen't make a ton of sense to me. Is there a way to define bits in python, such as 1 or 0. I guess b'h' must be in hex? Is there a way for me to simply define an eight bit string

```
bits1 = 10100000
```

Comment: "Data" is so broad as to be meaningless. You want *binary* data…?

Comment: Since you said your output includes a `b` prefix, I'm assuming this is Python 3 (because  `bytes == str`  in Python 2). If this is incorrect, please change it to indicate Python 2 is being used.

Answer (score 3):

You're conflating a number of unrelated things.

First of all, (in Python 3), quoted literals prefixed with `b` are of type `bytes` -- that means a string of raw byte values. Example:

```
x = b'abc'
print(type(x))     # will output `<class 'bytes'>`
```

This is in contrast to the `str` type, which is a (Unicode) string.

Integer literals can be expressed in binary using an `0b` prefix, e.g.

```
y = 0b10100000
print(y)           # Will output 160
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, 'data' is not a type. Your function (probably) accepts anything you pass to it, regardless of its type.

Now, `b'h'` means "the number (int) whose binary sequence maps to the char ´h´", this is not hexadecimal, but a number with possibly 8 bits (1 byte, which is the standard size for `int` and `char`).

The ASCII code for ´h´ is 104 (decimal), written in binary that would be b'\b01101000', or in hexa b'\x68'.

So, here is the answer I think you are looking for: if you want to code an 8-bit int from its binary representation just type `b'\b01101000'` (for 104). I would recommend to use hexa instead, to make it more compact and readable. In hexa, every four bits make a symbol from 0 to f, and the symbols can be concatenated every four bits to form a larger number. So the bit sequence 01101000 is written  b'\b0110\b1000' or b'\x6\x8', which can be written as b'\x68'. The preceding b, before the quote marks tells python to interpret the string as a binary sequence expressed in the base defined by \b or \x (or \d for decimal), instead of using escape characters.